# RASA --- ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, rasa

I am trying to install rasa and there is a problem with the tensorflow (Windows 10)

As a pre-requisite, I have installed Anaconda, VC++

Steps -

1. Open Anaconda with admin rights
2. activate rasa
3. pip install rasa-x --extra index url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
4. pip install rasa

Error - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

---

I tried to install tensorflow before installing rasa, apparently the error remains the same even for installing tensorflow .... Need some pointers to install rasa and tensorflow so that I can move ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and everything got fixed immediately ..
The main problem that I could notice at my set up was with the Visual Studio    installation that was not complete.

**Pre-requisites -**

1. Anaconda 64 Bit
2. Visual Studio complete installation

### Open Anaconda - **Admin privilege**
`mkdir c:\RASA`
`cd RASA`
`activate rasa`
`pip install rasa x extra index url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple`
`pip install rasa[full]`
`pip install rasa[spacy]`
`python -m spacy download en_core_web_md`
`python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en`

Following the above steps as mentioned solves all the issues wrt rasa installation.

Answer (score 0):

You need use Python version 3.6 or 3.7. Check on that
[image]